# How do I get my css component not be affected by global css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a navbar component, as well as a Navbar.module.css file.

**the navbar component file:**

```
import styleNavbar from '../../../styles/Main/Navbar.module.css'
```

It's supposed to make the navigation bar look nice, but what's happening instead is that everything but the buttons gets styled.  The buttons have changed back to the standard ones after I started using next-auth for social login.

**the app file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import styles from '../styles/tstyles.css'

export default function App({Component,pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider className={styles} session={session}>
      <div className={styles} >
      <Component className={styles} {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </SessionProvider>
    
  )
  };
```

The app file imports a **tailwind css file** that simply consists of the following:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**that's all the css i have in my app.  i'm very unfamiliar with how this works - but the styles on the nav bar were definitely showing before.**

**the full navbar.js**

```
import styleNavbar from "../../../styles/Main/Navbar.module.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

const NavButtonCreator = (props) => {
  const { mainprops, userprops, navbar, navprops, ...styleprops } = props;

  return (
    <button
      href="#"
      className={`${styleNavbar.menu__link} ${styleNavbar.r_link} ${styleNavbar.text_underlined}`}
      {...props}
      onClick={() => {
        navbar.makeButtonClick(!navbar.buttonClick);
        navbar.setButtonChoice(navprops.navbutton);
      }}
    >
      {navprops.navbutton}
    </button>
  );
};

const NavButtonStyler = (props) => {
  const { mainprops, userprops, navbar, ...navprops } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {props.place == "left" && (
        <div className="">
          <NavButtonCreator
            mainprops={mainprops}
            userprops={userprops}
            navbar={navbar}
            navprops={navprops}
          />
        </div>
      )}

      {props.place == "center" && (
        <div className="absolute left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 ">
          <NavButtonCreator
            mainprops={mainprops}
            userprops={userprops}
            navbar={navbar}
            navprops={navprops}
          />
        </div>
      )}

      {props.place == "right" && (
        <div className="absolute right-0">
          <NavButtonCreator
            mainprops={mainprops}
            userprops={userprops}
            navbar={navbar}
            navprops={navprops}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const Navbar = (props) => {
  const { mainprops, ...userprops } = props;
  const [buttonClick, makeButtonClick] = useState(false);
  const [buttonChoice, setButtonChoice] = useState(userprops.pageId);

  const navbar = {
    buttonClick,
    makeButtonClick,
    setButtonChoice,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buttonChoice == "log out") {
      signOut();
    }
    userprops.makeRefresh(!userprops.refresh);
    userprops.setPageId(buttonChoice);
  }, [buttonClick]);

  if (userprops.visitorType == "viewer") {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav
          className={`${styleNavbar.page__menu} ${styleNavbar.page__custom_settings} ${styleNavbar.menu}`}
        >
          <ul className={`${styleNavbar.menu__list} ${styleNavbar.r_list}`}>
            <NavButtonStyler
              mainprops={mainprops}
              userprops={userprops}
              navbar={navbar}
              place="left"
              navbutton="uno"
            />
            <NavButtonStyler
              mainprops={mainprops}
              userprops={userprops}
              navbar={navbar}
              place="left"
              navbutton="dos"
            />
            <NavButtonStyler
              mainprops={mainprops}
              userprops={userprops}
              navbar={navbar}
              place="left"
              navbutton="tres"
            />
            <NavButtonStyler
              mainprops={mainprops}
              userprops={userprops}
              navbar={navbar}
              place="center"
              navbutton="four"
            />
            <NavButtonStyler
              mainprops={mainprops}
              userprops={userprops}
              navbar={navbar}
              place="right"
              navbutton="i dont speak spanish"
            />
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Navbar;
```

**Navbar.module.css file:**

```
/*
=====
DEPENDENCES
=====
*/

.r_link{
  display: var(--rLinkDisplay, inline-flex) !important;
}

.r_link[href]{
  color: var(--rLinkColor) !important;
  text-decoration: var(--rLinkTextDecoration, none) !important;
}

.r_list{
  padding-left: var(--rListPaddingLeft, 0) !important;
  margin-top: var(--rListMarginTop, 0) !important;
  margin-bottom: var(--rListMarginBottom, 0) !important;
  list-style: var(--rListListStyle, none) !important;
}


/*
=====
CORE STYLES
=====
*/

.menu{
  --rLinkColor: var(--menuLinkColor, currentColor);
}

.menu__link{
  display: var(--menuLinkDisplay, block);
}

/* 
focus state 
*/

.menu__link:focus{
  outline: var(--menuLinkOutlineWidth, 2px) solid var(--menuLinkOutlineColor, currentColor);
  outline-offset: var(--menuLinkOutlineOffset);
}

/* 
fading siblings
*/

.menu:hover .menu__link:not(:hover){
  --rLinkColor: var(--menuLinkColorUnactive, #2e354b);
}

/*
=====
PRESENTATION STYLES
=====
*/

.menu{
  background-color: var(--menuBackgroundColor, #2e354b);
  box-shadow: var(--menuBoxShadow, 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24));
}

.menu__list{
  display: flex;  
}

.menu__link{
  padding: var(--menuLinkPadding, 1.5rem 2.5rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* 
=====
TEXT UNDERLINED
=====
*/

.text_underlined{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  will-change: color;
  transition: color .25s ease-out;  
}

.text_underlined::before, 
.text_underlined::after{
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: var(--textUnderlinedLineColor, currentColor);

  will-change: width;
  transition: width .1s ease-out;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.text_underlined::before{
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); 
}

.text_underlined::after{
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%); 
}

.text_underlined:hover::before, 
.text_underlined:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
  transition-duration: .2s;
}

/*
=====
SETTINGS
=====
*/

.page__custom_settings{
  --menuBackgroundColor: #2e354b;
  --menuLinkColor: #eed994;
  --menuLinkColorUnactive: #2e354b;
  --menuLinkOutlineOffset: -.5rem; 
}


/*
=====
DEMO
=====
*/

.body{
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Open Sans, Ubuntu, Fira Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 640px;
  padding-left: .75rem;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.page__menu:nth-child(n+2){
  margin-top: 3rem;
}


.substack{
  border:1px solid #EEE; 
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 1rem auto;;
}
```

**PS - i didnt write that css code**

Answer (score 1):

i installed `autoprefixer`

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  }
```

`npm install autoprefixer`

now the styles all look great....but the social auth doesn't work!!

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using NextJS, and If your using Tailwind why are you using CSS Modules?

`npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project`  will create a working NextJS + TailwindCSS project for you.

Comment: hey thanks for taking the time! i used the css because i copied that style for the navbar..not sure how to combine the two! but it worked before

Comment: ok i looked it all over - i had actually already setup the ```postcss.config.js``` and ```tailwind.config.js``` files - i think it's just something went wrong with the buttons - because the navbar does have the rest of the styles working